# Visua Studio 2015 Database Project: Unable to generate change script

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, database-project

In Visual Studio 2015, after I did a Schema Comparison between my database project and an existing database, I could see the changes, but the 'Update Target' and 'Generate Script' buttons were grayed out. How can I make them enabled so that I can generate the change scripts? (I have access to the target database and privilege to make changes.)  [image: screenshot]

Comment: Maybe do you have something on the Error List?

Comment: There is no error from the schema comparison, however, there are a bunch of errors from building the project, will those matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your Error List for errors or warnings after comparing.

Comment: The database project is created based on an existing database, I did notice there are a bunch of reference errors, but those are from building the project, will that errors stop me generating the change script?

Comment: You guys are right. After resolving the errors, I can generate the change scripts. Thanks a lot for your help.